# Gallery with option of saving image, android

Tags: android

i have implement gallery widget,
i just wanted to provide an option to user, that he can download images from gallery.
What to do in order to implement downloading options?
And i do have imageID and imageName, which user selects.

Suggestions needed

regards

Answer (score 0):

Well Shishir.bobby

Regarding your question I 'm assuming you have some images at the server that you are viewing as gallary images in your application.

For downloading the images you might need File handling support. Then on getting that file as output stream you have to write it to phone's gallary.